# How do I set a default Value in a dropdown menu in Fable Elmish?

Tags: drop-down-menu, f#, default, fable-f#, elmish

i want to have a default value in the dropdown that isnt one of the choosable options (not: DefaultValue "2").
It should be something like the following but not for an input-field.

```
Input.Placeholder "Your name here"
```

( i tried Placeholder in Select, but it didnt work)

Once you've opened the dropdown the default value should be listed the in  grey and italic (or something like that). I've recognized i can't change the font settings within the option properties of the select menu.

Thanks

```
Select.select
[ ]
[ select
    [
        //DefaultValue "2"
    ]
    [
        option [ Value "1" ] [ str "1" ]
        option [ Value "2"] [ str "2" ]
        option [ Value "3"] [ str "3" ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Select.select
[ ]
[ select
    [ ]
    [
        option [ Value ""; Disabled true; Selected true ] [ str "Your name here" ]
        option [ Value "1" ] [ str "1" ]
        option [ Value "2"] [ str "2" ]
        option [ Value "3"] [ str "3" ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked but I can't set the Value as a default like with: DefaultValue "2". Was "Selected true" supppose to do that?

Comment: I found the problem. I had to change a parameter in the model and set it as the value of the select. Thank you.